# How can we resolve JAVA command line error (FatalError: Program Stack empty)?

Tags: java

I am new to java and I ran below command in the command line.

---

```
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\benchmark>Java -jar 
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\RES.jar 
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\cob\F9342ED0.COB
```

---

But I am getting below error. could someone please suggest.

```
RES Cobol 2 Java alpha1.9(08/05/2010) - COPYRIGHT 2009
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\cob\F9342ED0.COB
Parsing Cobol started for: C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\cob\F9342ED0.COB
Translation to Java started.
The java classes are under the folder: C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\benchmark
Classes from translation of programs reside in the package: cobolprogramclasses
Classes from translation of data levels reside in the package: coboldataclasses
FatalError: Program Stack empty
Done.
```

I ran below command on the command line.

```
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\benchmark>Java -jar 
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\RES.jar 
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\cob\F9342ED0.COB


C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\benchmark>Java -jar 
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\RES.jar 
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\cob\F9342ED0.COB
```

The command convert cobol code to java.

Could you please suggest any other ways can we migrate COBOL to Java.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Java code is running correctly, but it's hitting an internal error. Maybe it couldn't find the directory with the Java sources.

```
C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\cob\F9342ED0.COB Translation to Java started. The java classes are under the folder: C:\Users\kranji1\Desktop\New\RES\benchmark Classes from translation of programs reside in the package: cobolprogramclasses Classes from translation of data levels reside in the package: coboldataclasses FatalError: Program Stack empty Done.
```

Unless you have the sources to that JAR file, and post them in your question, you'll have to talk to whoever provided the Cobol-to-Java translation JAR.

Comment: Hi actually i have downloaded the jar from below site and followed instructions.

http://opencobol2java.sourceforge.net/

i don't see any contact so I approached here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a COBOL to Java tool in the translators.zip at: https://agilemde.co.uk/

It covers mainly COBOL 74 and the main forms of statement, and can be extended/customised.